# Why I am getting this error for advanced Q3

Tags: rpa, g1ant

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlEC6.png)

This is image error. Can anyone help me in solving this it would be a great help.

Comment: Can you add the code snippet from where this exception is being thrown? thanks.

Comment: In addition to adding the code that is throwing this error, as requested by @RobertDurgin, it would be useful to include the error message as text. That is easier for people to read, and will help other users with a similar problem find this post in the future.

Answer (score 0):

keyboard ⋘enter⋙
use it instead of the 6th line in the program which is
 selenium.presskey enter search btnK by name

Answer (score -1):

Use this syntax 'selenium.gettext search iUh30 by class result ♥url' at 9th line instead of
'selenium.gettext search //*[@id="rso"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/a[1]/div/cite by xpath result ♥url'
and at last line use this syntax 'selenium.click search LC20lb by class' instead of 'selenium.click search selenium.click search //*[@id="rso"]/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/a/h3 by xpath'

As xpath is different of each site and if their is any small mistake in xpath it will not work.